# Question about function design

Tags: c++

I just had an interview question about how I design a simple function - find the second largest number in an Int Array.

```
int findSecondLargest(int * arr, int len){
    int second = 0;
    ...

    return second;
}
```

However, I was asked the following questions about how I deal with the issues.

1. If the len is less than 2(I think we can return a special value, like 0, or MinInt.)
2. But, if the second largest is 0. (Since in this case, I can not differentiate between an error and a normal return value. so  I might throw an exception)
3. If the array is {1,1,1}(Since 1 is the largest number, not an second largest. so I might throw an exception)

I really felt confused. I think it is not possible to deal with all situations. We usually have to document the usage of our function, instead of throw exception.

Hope some advice. Thanks

//The function body is written by myself. I really like the design supposed by Donotalo and PigBen

Comment: Changed C tag to C++: As the original author is referring to exceptions, it is more a C++ question than a C question.

Comment: Why are cases 2 and 3 errors at all?  They seem to have perfectly reasonable results.  The answer to case 2 is 0, and the answer to case 3 is 1, at least in my opinion.

Comment: To clarify: Do you want to return 2nd largest value or the index of it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Following the standard library model, when searching a sequence, we don't return the value we are looking for, we return an iterator to the value(a pointer in this case).  If we don't find the value, we return an iterator to one past the last element, the signature would look like this:

```
// end is not the last element, it is one past the last element
int * findSecondLargest(int * begin, int * end);
```

Answer (score 2):

Is the function body given by the interviewer? If not, I'd write a function that returns the index of the second largest item in the array. If no second largest item is found (like your error cases), my function would return `len` to indicate that second largest item is not found.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with returning a 'special value', such as 0, is that the second largest number in the array *could* be 0.  How would you be able to tell the difference?

The function, as written, could not use it's return value to indicate when an error has occured.  You could either refactor it to return an error code and use an out parameter to fill out the found value (very C-style), or you could throw an exception (more C++ style).

EDIT:

It just occured to me that if the value returned is the *index* of the second largest number in the array, you could use negative numbers as 'special values'.

Answer (score 0):

Specificying the use of the function does not preclude dealing with corner cases. It just means that you explicitly document the behavior of the function in such cases.

Whether you throw an exception or return a specific (magic) value is up to you. You might also ask to change the return type so that you could have a richer diagnostic.

In any cases, it's good practice to think about the whole field of inputs. For example, here you've also forgotten to treat the case of `arr` being `NULL` or `len` being negative.

Answer (score 0):

Uses GCC-specific variable-number-of-args-to-macro notation just for testing, but anyway, basic ideas are:

> If the len is less than 2 (I think we can return a special value, like 0, or MinInt.)

- Here, I return a NULL pointer rather than a safe-to-dereference pointer, so there's no issue with having 0 or MinInt in the data.

> But, if the second largest is 0. (Since in this case, I can not differentiate between an error and a normal return value. so I might throw an exception)

An exception for a reasonable input is pretty seriously bad!

> If the array is {1,1,1}(Since 1 is the largest number, not an second largest. so I might throw an exception)

This is arguable, but that's the behaviour I've modelled, also by returning NULL.

So:

- differentiate a found condition from an unfound by using pointers vs NULL
- second-largest value can be maintained by tracking largest as we iterate once

Code's a bit scrappy, but FWIW:

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T, int N>
T* second_largest(T (&arr)[N])
{
    if (N < 2) return NULL;
    T* largest = &arr[0];
    T* second = NULL;
    for (int i = 1; i < N; ++i)
    {
        if (arr[i] > *largest)
        {
            second = largest;
            largest = &arr[i];
        }
        else if (arr[i] != *largest && (!second || arr[i] > *second))
            second = &arr[i];
        std::cout << "i " << i << ", largest " << (largest ? *largest : -1)
            << ", second " << (second ? *second : -1) << '\n';
    }
    return second;
}

#define TEST(ASSERTION, ARRAY...) \
{ \
    int x[] = { ARRAY }; \
    int* p = second_largest(x); \
    assert(ASSERTION); \
    std::cout << #ASSERTION << " passed for " << #ARRAY << '\n'; \
}

int main()
{
    TEST(*p == 4, 1, 3, 2, 5, 4, 0);
    TEST(!p, 1, 1, 1);
    TEST(!p, 1);
    TEST(*p == 1, 1, 2);
    TEST(*p == 1, 2, 1);
    TEST(*p == 1, 1, 2, 0);
    std::cout << "all tests passed\n";
}
```